# Zend and oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db, ora-01722

I'm trying to insert a new statement to Oracle. My aim is to create clean sql query.

I have a table containing ID, username, password.
I have following code

```
$sql = 'insert INTO EMPLOYEES (ID, LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES (:seq,  :login, :pass)';
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo_Oci(Zend_Registry::get('db'), $sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':seq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('RK.EMP_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL'),':login' => 'sss', ':pass' => 's'));
```

(registry stores oci_pdo adapter)

but it gives me:

> Message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1722 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01722:
>   invalid number
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:146)

I can't figure out what happens, because there is literally no info in google=(
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

How about just do this:

```
$sql = 'insert INTO EMPLOYEES (ID, LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES (RK.EMP_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,  :login, :pass)';
```

Now just bind the login and password and execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can inform Zend what is the name of your sequence:

```
<?php
class A extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_sequence = 'RK.EMP_SEQUENCE';
    ....
```